# Homology and homotopy of a surface

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, differential-topology, tag-removed

Suppose $S$ be a closed orientable genous $g$ surface. Let $f$,$g$ be homeomorphis from $S$ to itself. Assume they induce the same map on 1st homology $H_1(S, \mathbb Z).$

My question is; does this imply $f$, $g$ are homotopic or isotopic?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: No -- a Dehn twist about a nontrivial separating simple closed curve acts as the identity on homology, but is not nullhomotopic.  The keyword to search for is "Torelli group".

Comment: A thing to notice about your question is that homotopic homeomorphisms are automatically isotopic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Andy Putman's comment (Dehn twist on null-homologous curve; google for "Torelli group") is a concise and fairly complete answer to this question.  I'm posting this CW answer so that the question does not resurface later.

Comment: Wouldn't you prefer a simplicial answer? (What a stupid joke!)

Comment: Perhaps -- the possibilities for the answer were manifold.  (Another bad joke.)